# Can I style native elements when using React Native?

Tags: css, react-native, styling, custom-view

I'm looking at [react-native-desktop](https://github.com/ptmt/react-native-desktop) and I'm wondering if when using a  component for example I'll be able to style it however I want using CSS? I know for a fact that styling an NSSegmentedControl is far from easy and would be amazed if RN actually allows you to customise native elements by styling the component.

If not how does subclassing work with React Native? Is it even possible or you simply limited to native-looking controls and views.

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-desktop](https://github.com/ptmt/react-native-desktop) is just a fork of [react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native), so styles work the same as they do in React Native. Incase you're not familiar with React Native and how it implements styles, it uses a "CSS-in-JS" approach. I've included an example styles object below. Read more in the [Styles](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html) section of the [React Native Docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/).

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
  },
  background: {
    backgroundColor: '#c6c6c6',
  },
  active: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#0077CC',
  },
});
```